# How can I add/remove user specific data in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts

A few questions about storing user data in MongoDB. What is the best place in mongo to store user specific data, such as User settings, User photo url, User friends, User events?

In Mongo, user data is stored in:
Meteor

```
  / Collections
    / users
      / _id
        / profile
        / services
```

Should I add there a new collections? In a following way:

```
        / events / _id's
        / friends / _id's
        / messages / _id's
        / settings
```

How should I publish user's private data and manipulate this collections, to be sure it's save and no one else will modify or have access to private data of another person.

Answer (score 1):

## Normalization

["Database normalization is the process of organizing the attributes and tables of a relational database to minimize data redundancy."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

MongoDB is a non relational database. This makes normalized data hard to query for. This is why in MongoDB we denormalize data. That makes querying for it easier.

It depends on your use-case. The question is basically when to demormalize. It's mostly a matter of opinion. But *objective* here are some pros and cons:

#### Pros to demormalization

- It's easier to retrieve data (Due to Mongo not beeing a relational DB)
- It performs better if you are always getting the data in bulk

#### Cons to demormalization

- It doesn't scale well for things like `user.messages` (You can't just publicize some messages)

In your case I'd definitly go for seperate collections for `events`, `friends` and `messages`. Setting can't expand *infinitly*. So I'd put it into the `users` collection.

## Security

I'd use a publications and allow and deny for this. Let me make an example for `Messages`:

#### [Collection](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection)

```
Messages = new Mongo.Collection('Messages')

Messages.insert({
  sender: Meteor.userId,
  recipient: Meteor.users.findOne()._id,
  message: 'Hello world!'
})
```

#### [Publication](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish)

```
Meteor.publish('userMessages', function (limit) {
  return Messages.subscribe({
    $or: [
      {sender: this.userId},
      {recipient: this.userId}
    ]
  }, {limit: limit})
})
```

#### [Allow](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow)

```
function ownsMessage (user, msg) {
  return msg.sender === user ? true : false
}

Messages.allow({
  insert: function (userId, newDoc) {
    !!userId
  },
  update: function (userId, oldDoc, newDoc) {
    if(
      ownsMessage(userId, oldDoc) &&
      ownsMessage(userId, newDoc)
    ) return true
    return false
  },
  remove: function () {
    return false
  }
})
```

*This code is untested, so it might contain small errors*

Comment: Ok after reading suggestions, that's what I get: demormalization is related to publishing entire collection of some data, normalization is related to publishing only a part of collection. And, for normalized messages You used `subscribe` (to userId messages) instead of `find`, then set Allow rules only if user `ownsMessage`.

Comment: I added an explanation for denormalization on top of my answer. Your understanding of it is a little off. Sorry about the confusion, I thought you knew what it was. For infos on subscribe and find please read the [official docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/). I also added links to relevant places of the docs in my answer. If you still have questions after that, I'll be glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add data to the users profile field like this:

```
Meteor.users.update( id, { $set: { 'profile.friends': someValue } } );
```

To only publish specific fields you can do something like this:

```
Meteor.publish( 'users', function () {
    return Meteor.users.find( {}, { fields: { 'profile.friends': 1 } } );
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Replaced `Meteor.users.find( {},...` with `Meteor.users.find( {_id: this.userId},...` in order to receive only my private data. Hmm, when database will hit 10.000 users it may kill the server if every user will receive 10.000 friend lists, I think.